# Use of punctuation with the word 'that'

Tags: punctuation

Can anyone make it very easy to understand for me what the rules are on using punctuation before the word 'that'?

Comment: Here is an example where people might be tempted to add a comma: He noted having nightmares on a weekly basis in the aftermath of the accident that are slowly receding over time - NOT PUNCTUATED? He noted having nightmares on a weekly basis in the aftermath of the accident, that are slowly receding over time - PUNCTUATED?  Which is correct?

Comment: I prefer without for this example I've given above, but I wanted to find out what's technically correct in usage.  I note that MS Word puts a blue wavy line underneath the punctuation indicating an error, but obviously it's a robot and perhaps not always correct? Yea, nay?

Comment: Consider editing the sentence to make it clearer that the phrase _that are slowly receding_ refers to the nightmares. As it stands, it's confusing with or without the comma.

Comment: Hi Kate, can you clarify why you feel it's confusing? If I was writing it, I'd probably write it as: He noted having nightmares on weekly basis in the aftermath of the accident, which are slowly receding over time. Is this what you mean - to replace the word 'that' with something more grammatically correct? This comes up quite a lot for me, the 'that' problem. I will try and gather some further examples. (NOTE: Unfortunately, I'm typing verbatim and therefore I am unable to edit the work.)  But if it's incorrect, I'd like to know. Can anyone comment?

Comment: Well, that version is better, but I was thinking of something like 'In the aftermath of the accident, he noted, he had had nightmares on a weekly basis, but they are slowly receding over time.'

Comment: Again, I'm unable to edit the work - I was really looking for some guidance on proper usage here, rather than suggestions for edits. Thanks meantime though. Perhaps it's simply incorrect. I'm a bit confused. Would be good to get some input.